# Making a UDP server/client program that traces more statistics

Tags: java, udp, client-server, sliding-window

I am new to programming server/client programs. I just learned how to do Stop-and-Wait but I wanted to try my hand at Go-Back-N. I made a program that will allow a simple file transfer but I want to be able to get more info from it like I did in my Stop-and-Wait like: the total number of data packets transmitted,the total number of acknowledgments sent, the total number of acknowledgments received, the total number of duplicate packets received, the total amount of data sent and a log file of actions, recording all activities between the client and server.

I have some of the more basic statistics done like number of retransmissions, transfer time, and notice of sent file but this only works on one file at a time. I want to be able to send multiple packets.

Here is my code so far:

Receiver:

```
public class Receiver {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Ready to receive the file!");

    // Get the address, port and name of file to send over UDP
    final int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    final String fileName = args[1];

    receiveAndCreate(port, fileName);
}

public static void receiveAndCreate(int port, String fileName) throws IOException {
    // Create the socket, set the address and create the file to be sent
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    InetAddress address;
    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileOutputStream outToFile = new FileOutputStream(file);

    // Create a flag to indicate the last message
    boolean lastMessageFlag = false;

    // Store sequence number
    int sequenceNumber = 0;
    int lastSequenceNumber = 0;

    // For each message we will receive
    while (!lastMessageFlag) {
        // Create byte array for full message and another for file data without header
        byte[] message = new byte[1024];
        byte[] fileByteArray = new byte[1021];

        // Receive packet and retreive message
        DatagramPacket receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
        socket.setSoTimeout(0);
        socket.receive(receivedPacket);
        message = receivedPacket.getData();

        // Get port and address for sending ack
        address = receivedPacket.getAddress();
        port = receivedPacket.getPort();

        // Retrieve sequence number
        sequenceNumber = ((message[0] & 0xff) << 8) + (message[1] & 0xff);

        // Retrieve the last message flag
        if ((message[2] & 0xff) == 1) {
            lastMessageFlag = true;
        } else {
            lastMessageFlag = false;
        }

        if (sequenceNumber == (lastSequenceNumber + 1)) {

            // Update latest sequence number
            lastSequenceNumber = sequenceNumber;

            // Retrieve data from message
            for (int i=3; i < 1024 ; i++) {
                fileByteArray[i-3] = message[i];
            }

            // Write the message to the file
            outToFile.write(fileByteArray);
            System.out.println("Received: Sequence number = " + sequenceNumber +", Flag = " + lastMessageFlag);

            // Send acknowledgement
            sendAck(lastSequenceNumber, socket, address, port);

            // Check for last message
            if (lastMessageFlag) {
                outToFile.close();
            } 
        } else {
            // If packet has been received, send ack for that packet again
            if (sequenceNumber < (lastSequenceNumber + 1)) {
                // Send acknowledgement for received packet
                sendAck(sequenceNumber, socket, address, port);
            } else {
                // Resend acknowledgement for last packet received
                sendAck(lastSequenceNumber, socket, address, port);
            }
        }
    }

    socket.close();
    System.out.println("File " + fileName + " has been received.");


}
public static void sendAck(int lastSequenceNumber, DatagramSocket socket, InetAddress address, int port) throws IOException {
    // Resend acknowledgement
    byte[] ackPacket = new byte[2];
    ackPacket[0] = (byte)(lastSequenceNumber >> 8);
    ackPacket[1] = (byte)(lastSequenceNumber);
    DatagramPacket acknowledgement = new  DatagramPacket(ackPacket, ackPacket.length, address, port);
    socket.send(acknowledgement);
    System.out.println("Sent ack: Sequence Number = " + lastSequenceNumber);
}
}
```

Sender:

```
public class Sender {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Get the address, port and name of file to send over UDP
        final String hostName = args[0];
        final int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        final String fileName = args[2];

        createAndSend(hostName, port, fileName);
    }

    public static void createAndSend(String hostName, int port, String fileName) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Sending the file");

        // Create the socket, set the address and create the file to be sent
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
        File file = new File(fileName); 

        // Create a byte array to store the filestream
        InputStream inFromFile = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] fileByteArray = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        inFromFile.read(fileByteArray);

        // Start timer for calculating throughput
        StartTime timer = new StartTime(0);

        // Create a flag to indicate the last message and a 16-bit sequence number
        int sequenceNumber = 0;
        boolean lastMessageFlag = false;

        // Create a flag to indicate the last acknowledged message and a 16-bit sequence number
        int ackSequenceNumber = 0;
        int lastAckedSequenceNumber = 0;
        boolean lastAcknowledgedFlag = false;

        // Create a counter to count number of retransmissions and initialize window size
        int retransmissionCounter = 0;
        int windowSize = 128;

        // Vector to store the sent messages
        Vector <byte[]> sentMessageList = new Vector <byte[]>();

        // For as each message we will create
        for (int i=0; i < fileByteArray.length; i = i+1021 ) {

            // Increment sequence number
            sequenceNumber += 1;

            // Create new byte array for message
            byte[] message = new byte[1024];

            // Set the first and second bytes of the message to the sequence number
            message[0] = (byte)(sequenceNumber >> 8);
            message[1] = (byte)(sequenceNumber);

            // Set flag to 1 if packet is last packet and store it in third byte of header
            if ((i+1021) >= fileByteArray.length) {
                lastMessageFlag = true;
                message[2] = (byte)(1);
            } else { // If not last message store flag as 0
                lastMessageFlag = false;
                message[2] = (byte)(0);
            }

            // Copy the bytes for the message to the message array
            if (!lastMessageFlag) {
                for (int j=0; j != 1021; j++) {
                    message[j+3] = fileByteArray[i+j];
                }
            }
            else if (lastMessageFlag) { // If it is the last message
                for (int j=0;  j < (fileByteArray.length - i); j++) {
                    message[j+3] = fileByteArray[i+j];
                }
            }

            // Package the message
            DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length, address, port);

            // Add the message to the sent message list
            sentMessageList.add(message);

            while (true) {
                // If next sequence number is outside the window
                if ((sequenceNumber - windowSize) > lastAckedSequenceNumber) {

                    boolean ackRecievedCorrect = false;
                    boolean ackPacketReceived = false;

                    while (!ackRecievedCorrect) {
                        // Check for an ack
                        byte[] ack = new byte[2];
                        DatagramPacket ackpack = new DatagramPacket(ack, ack.length);

                        try {
                            socket.setSoTimeout(50);
                            socket.receive(ackpack);
                            ackSequenceNumber = ((ack[0] & 0xff) << 8) + (ack[1] & 0xff);
                            ackPacketReceived = true;
                        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                            ackPacketReceived = false;
                            //System.out.println("Socket timed out while waiting for an acknowledgement");
                            //e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        if (ackPacketReceived) {
                            if (ackSequenceNumber >= (lastAckedSequenceNumber + 1)) {
                                lastAckedSequenceNumber = ackSequenceNumber;
                            }
                            ackRecievedCorrect = true;
                            System.out.println("Ack recieved: Sequence Number = " + ackSequenceNumber);
                            break;  // Break if there is an ack so the next packet can be sent
                        } else { // Resend the packet
                            System.out.println("Resending: Sequence Number = " + sequenceNumber);
                            // Resend the packet following the last acknowledged packet and all following that (cumulative acknowledgement)
                            for (int y=0; y != (sequenceNumber - lastAckedSequenceNumber); y++) {
                                byte[] resendMessage = new byte[1024];
                                resendMessage = sentMessageList.get(y + lastAckedSequenceNumber);

                                DatagramPacket resendPacket = new DatagramPacket(resendMessage, resendMessage.length, address, port);
                                socket.send(resendPacket);
                                retransmissionCounter += 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else { // Else pipeline is not full, break so we can send the message
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Send the message
            socket.send(sendPacket);
            System.out.println("Sent: Sequence number = " + sequenceNumber + ", Flag = " + lastMessageFlag);


            // Check for acknowledgements
            while (true) {
                boolean ackPacketReceived = false;
                byte[] ack = new byte[2];
                DatagramPacket ackpack = new DatagramPacket(ack, ack.length);

                try {
                    socket.setSoTimeout(10);
                    socket.receive(ackpack);
                    ackSequenceNumber = ((ack[0] & 0xff) << 8) + (ack[1] & 0xff);
                    ackPacketReceived = true;
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    //System.out.println("Socket timed out waiting for an ack");
                    ackPacketReceived = false;
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }

                // Note any acknowledgements and move window forward
                if (ackPacketReceived) {
                    if (ackSequenceNumber >= (lastAckedSequenceNumber + 1)) {
                        lastAckedSequenceNumber = ackSequenceNumber;
                        System.out.println("Ack recieved: Sequence number = " + ackSequenceNumber);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Continue to check and resend until we receive final ack
        while (!lastAcknowledgedFlag) {

            boolean ackRecievedCorrect = false;
            boolean ackPacketReceived = false;

            while (!ackRecievedCorrect) {
                // Check for an ack
                byte[] ack = new byte[2];
                DatagramPacket ackpack = new DatagramPacket(ack, ack.length);

                try {
                    socket.setSoTimeout(50);
                    socket.receive(ackpack);
                    ackSequenceNumber = ((ack[0] & 0xff) << 8) + (ack[1] & 0xff);
                    ackPacketReceived = true;
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                    //System.out.println("Socket timed out waiting for an ack1");
                    ackPacketReceived = false;
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // If its the last packet
                if (lastMessageFlag) {
                    lastAcknowledgedFlag = true;
                    break;
                } 
                // Break if we receive acknowledgement so that we can send next packet
                    if (ackPacketReceived) {  
                    System.out.println("Ack recieved: Sequence number = " + ackSequenceNumber);
                    if (ackSequenceNumber >= (lastAckedSequenceNumber + 1)) {
                        lastAckedSequenceNumber = ackSequenceNumber;
                    }
                    ackRecievedCorrect = true;
                    break; // Break if there is an ack so the next packet can be sent
                } else { // Resend the packet
                    // Resend the packet following the last acknowledged packet and all following that (cumulative acknowledgement)
                    for (int j=0; j != (sequenceNumber-lastAckedSequenceNumber); j++) {
                        byte[] resendMessage = new byte[1024];
                        resendMessage = sentMessageList.get(j + lastAckedSequenceNumber);
                        DatagramPacket resendPacket = new DatagramPacket(resendMessage, resendMessage.length, address, port);
                        socket.send(resendPacket);
                        System.out.println("Resending: Sequence Number = " + lastAckedSequenceNumber);

                        // Increment retransmission counter
                        retransmissionCounter += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        socket.close();
        System.out.println("File " + fileName + " has been sent");

        // Calculate the average throughput
        int fileSizeKB = (fileByteArray.length) / 1024;
        int transferTime = timer.getTimeElapsed() / 1000;
        double throughput = (double) fileSizeKB / transferTime;
        System.out.println("File size: " + fileSizeKB + "KB, Transfer time: " + transferTime + " seconds. Throughput: " + throughput + "KBps");
        System.out.println("Number of retransmissions: " + retransmissionCounter); 
    }
}
```

I guess my main problem is converting it from accepting just one file into multiple?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to be more specific. It is very hard to look at the entire code.

Comment: I just found a project that is similar to what I want to do, it says: collect statistics. Collect statistics for both the client and server. After transferring a file print out the following suggested statistics   
1. the total number of data packets transmitted  2. the total number of retransmissions  3. the total number of acknowledgments sent  4. the total number of acknowledgments received  5. the total number of duplicate packets received  6. the total amount of data sent.  7. A log file of actions, recording all activities between the client and server. @prasanth

Comment: That is good to know

Comment: I don't know how to implement it though. I'm at a lost.

Comment: I will be able to help you because I have implemented these two protocols in C for my college project.

Comment: Can you use a datastructure to maintain the information about each file?

Comment: Do you want your server to send multiple files at the same time?

Comment: I want it to send just one file for now until I can build up to multiple files and any data-structure would work for maintaining the information but I would prefer to send it straight to the screen so that I can check it myself

Comment: I don't get it yet. You print all the details in the screen, , don't you? What else do you need?